# How do I use cmd + F to do text search in gerrit review?

Tags: gerrit

I found it really annoying that I can't even search for a piece of text that's right under my eye in gerrit. I am not even asking for full text search like google's code search. Is this function supported at all in gerrit? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to press "/" in the diff view to search in the text using "Vim-like" style. See more details [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-review-ui.html#search). Unfortunately this feature is only working in the Gerrit old UI. The "/" search is broken in the new UI and there's [an open bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=9369) for this.